# Зачем нужны эти исправления?

Tags: android, android-xml

Android Studio предлагает какие-то исправления для EditText. Подскажите нужны ли они мне, что от них измениться?

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/Height"
            style="@style/textPole"
            android:layout_width="70sp"
            android:layout_height="26sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/for_text_pole"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/sm"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvHeight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvHeight" />
```

[image: предлагаемые исправления]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фреймворк Автозаполенения.

Фреймворк автозаполнения управляет связью между приложением и сервисом автозаполнения.

Все это дело нужно для того, что бы пользователь не вводили многократно одни и те же данные.

Плюсы в основном:

- Минимизиирует количество ошибок, которые может допустить пользователь во время заполнения
- Предоставляет быстрое заполнение полей и на это тратится меньше времени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**android:autofillHints**  Предлагает указать, какой тип содержимого должен быть там размещен

```
android:autofillHints="username" // Тип содержимого, который должен быть так размещен
```

**android:importantForAutofill** Нужен, чтобы указать autofill какие представления вы хотите (или не хотите) заполнять. Для этого есть много разных значений, например: no,noExcludeDescendants,yes и т.д.

```
android:importantForAutofill="no" // Сказать, что это View(EditText) не важно для заполнения
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!